# Scroll down is not working in google chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, scroll

Hi i really need help on this one, I still can't figure out whats wrong with the scroll down in my website.

The problem:
-As soon as I resize my browser window to a smaller screen, the scroll down stops working
-The problem is happening only in Chrome

this is my website [www.outrippers.cl][1]

Comment: I have tested your website on chrome 48 and 49 on Mac, scroll  is working just fine *(up and domn)*. Have you updated your Chrome browser? Another thing when going to contact, the menu become responsive, is that normal?

Comment: Yes i have 49 en windows, it doesnt work for me

Comment: Have you check if you have some Chrome add ons that could interfere with?

Comment: yes, i disable all extensions and still didnt work, it works at the very begining (5 seconds), and then it doesnt

Comment: @pein did you solve it? I have another case and it's really strange. In Mac and Linux with Google Chrome it does work. Not in Windows 10 though.